# What are the sandbox values when I want to embed my react app into another website?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, embed, sandbox

I am trying to make the embedded version of my react app, just like the YouTube embedded tool. I create a simple index.html file and put this line:

```
<iframe src=[web url] width="500" height="500" allowFullScreen sandbox=""/\>
```

The Chrome browser gave me this error:

> Blocked script execution in [web url] because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

The error is understandable because I am embedding a react app. Change the line to the following:

```
<iframe src=[web url] width="500" height="500" allowFullScreen sandbox="allow-scripts"/\>
```

Then I get a different error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Finally,

```
<iframe src=[web url] width="500" height="500" allowFullScreen sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"/\>
```

gave me no error. However, here comes my problem, in [MDN web document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies#iframes_in_detail), it says:

> One important note is that you should never add both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin to your sandbox attribute — in that case, the embedded content could bypass the Same-origin policy that stops sites from executing scripts, and use JavaScript to turn off sandboxing altogether.

Apparently, the way I embedded my react app is violating the rule suggested by MDN docs. Can someone tell me what is a better solution?

Thank you.

Written in the question description.